# correct IAM configuration/binding for cloud run to be able to invoke other cloud run service? preferably using terraform

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-run, terraform-provider-gcp, google-iam, infrastructure-as-code

I have a cloud run services called `gateway` and it must access a few other services, let's call them `auth-service` and `user-service`.

The issue I'm having is constantly getting the classic 403s despite trying several iAM bindings.

They all share the same service account, attached via terraform like this:

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "gateway" {
...
    spec {
      service_account_name = module.cloudrun-sa.email
```

Then, I have the following code to add some bindings for the policy based on the google documentation here: `https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#terraform`

```
data "google_iam_policy" "private" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/run.invoker"
    members = [
      "serviceAccount:${module.cloudrun-sa.email}",
    ]
  }
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_policy" "allow-gateway-to-invoke-auth-service" {
  service     = google_cloud_run_service.auth-service.name
  location    = google_cloud_run_service.auth-service.location
  project     = var.gcp_project
  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.private.policy_data
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_policy" "allow-gateway-to-invoke-user-service" {
  service     = google_cloud_run_service.user-service.name
  location    = google_cloud_run_service.user-service.location
  project     = var.gcp_project
  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.private.policy_data
}
```

Unfortunately this continues to result in 403s.

I've also tried 3-4 other methods suggested by ChatGPT with the same result.

#### EDIT

Changing the policy to "all" instead of that specific account fixes the issue, so I'm guessing the request isn't made correctly/right.

With the help of @John Hanley I have looked in the logs and got this error:

```
The request was not authenticated. Either allow unauthenticated invocations or set the proper Authorization header. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#unauthorized-client"
```

This is in the logs of one of the services that the gateway is trying to access.

I was under the impression that I do not have to authenticate anything myself manually. I'll dig more into the docs.

Comment: Edit your question with one of the Google Cloud Logging log entries (expanded) showing the failure.

Comment: @JohnHanley this is simply the http request made via apollo returning a 403:Forbidden, no more details, as if I'd try to invoke the service in the browser myself.

There's no failure to bind the policies.

Comment: I meant the log entry for the Cloud Run service. That will show you the identity that made the request and more details. Your question shows details on the configuration but not on the service error. Client request authorization is managed before your service is called. Those details are logged.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't realize that was available, edited my question with that.

Comment: When making the HTTP request, are you adding the `Authorization: Bearer <OIDC IDENTITY TOKEN>` to the request? https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#acquire-token